# ruby cp ignores access permissions if not pointing to specific file

Tags: ruby, file-permissions, cp

I have following code:

```
def post_install

  cp Dir[lib/"directory/defaultconfigs/*"], etc/"directory"
```

While the snippet above ignores the access permissions,

```
cp Dir[lib/"directory/defaultconfigs/testfile.d"], etc/"directory"
```

does not ignore it.
How do I get the first command to copy all files including their permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself, with `cp_r` you can add the preserve option which keeps permissions as-is.

The line `cp_r Dir[lib/"directory/defaultconfigs/*"], etc/"directory", :preserve => true` works for me.